# How to prevent refreshing the page continuously when add Chosen Image in Asp .net document ready function

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, jquery-chosen, prototype-chosen

In one of my ASP.Net project I have used the chosen-image (https://github.com/djgrant/chosen-image) for add images to drop down list.

I added chosen library as well. Everything work fine for chosen. It will create the chosen list view if I use following code in document load function.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
          $(".chosen-select").chosen({
              disable_search_threshold: 10
                 });
    }
```

Then I wanted to add images to list view. So i added chosen-image js file and css files and changed the above code as following.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
              $(".chosen-select").chosenImage({
                  disable_search_threshold: 10
                     });
        }
```

in the back end I am binding the images to list view.

```
protected void Bind_BuyerImages() {
        if (cmbBuyer != null)
        {
            foreach (ListItem li in cmbBuyer.Items)
            {
                li.Attributes["data-img-src"] = "../Buyers/" + li.Value; 
            }
        }
    }
```

In the list view all the images are showing but page is refreshing continuously. How can i prevent this ?

Comment: by `page is refreshing continuously` what do you mean? is it refreshing based on any condition? lik a btn click? when exactly the refreshing is happening. also it would be great if you can reproduce the same problem in a fiddle and share with us.

Comment: @Cerlin Boss page is reloading continuously if i add $(".chosen-select").chosenImage({ }); in the ready function. It won't stop

Comment: i am unable to locate any code which `reloads` the page. any demo links?

Comment: Are you using HTML helper to load list ? Can you update that code ?

Comment: List is loaded as data table and bind it to the listView at the page load function

Comment: What happen if you don't add the `data-img-src` to the `li`, did the `chosenImage` work and not `refreshing continuously`? How about if you `hard coded` the `li` with `data-img-src` attribute in the `HTML` without binding it on page load, is it still `refreshing`?

Comment: @Kyojimaru if i added chosenImage instead of chosen then it will start refreshing without binding or not. it will ok if i use chosen. but there is no way to bind image.

Comment: @BPSK, did you use the same `chosen` that's included inside the git of `chosenImage` which is updated 2 Years ago, or did you use the newest `chosen` from [here](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)? Perhaps it's the error with the `chosen` version if you use the newest one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how the results of `chosenImage` should look like, because I can't see the example from the `Git`, but there's a forked `chosen` version which allow you to customize the `item` inside the `list` that you can use from [here](https://github.com/cjstewart88/chosen/tree/templates)

then you can call the function like this

```
$('.chosen-select').chosen({
    template: function (text, templateData) {
        return "<img src='" + templateData.imgsrc + "'></img> <span>" + text + "</span>";
    }
});
```

if you need to change the style of the `item`, just add `class` for it's template (`img` and `span` for this example), then style it with the `class` from the `CSS`

then when you bind the `list`, change it to

```
foreach (ListItem li in cmbBuyer.Items)
{
    li.Attributes["data-imgsrc"] = "../Buyers/" + li.Value; 
}
```

### Edit:

After I recheck it, it only pass 2 parameters in the `template` function, so you need to change

```
template: function (text, value, templateData)
```

to

```
template: function (text, templateData)
```

Here's an example of the custom template: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyojimaru/qn6bvgg5/) (The `CSS` doesn't load when I try it in the Fiddle), try to change your template to what you need.

Comment: I tried the above example but i get the error "Cannot read property 'imgsrc' of undefined"

Comment: Thanks. It worked. is there a way to show the image of the selected index. in the top.

Comment: you need to change the `script` if you want to do that I think, find `Chosen.prototype.set_up_html`, then change the `this.container.html` inside `if (this.is_multiple) { ... } else { ... }` to what you need.